# Is it possible to use ABS cement to glue together threaded ABS union fitting on P-trap for permanent connection?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, cement, p-trap, abs

Is it possible to use ABS cement for threaded ABS union fitting on P-trap for permanent connection? Or it won't be secure enough even if it glued together with cement?

Or need to actually replace with a P-Trap with union that glues together with cement.

Comment: Are you concerned that the threaded connection will come loose?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: A union IS a permanent connection. It happens to be a permanent connection that can be disassembled, but glue won't improve it in any way.

Comment: George yes is an answer, I would not do it but it would seize the threads forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever glue a fitting that is designed for threaded pressure fit.

The threaded fittment allows the piping to be lined up then tightened for a leak free connection. Nobody but an expert could possibly line up hard glued piping under a sink. The standard fittings sealed by plastic seals, held by threaded connections, has a range of adjustment in translation and rotation about multiple axes to give leak free connections.

Sweated copper drains can be lined up because they can be adjusted to fit and then all the joints sweated at the end without disturbing the fit. This cannot be done with glue joints. AFIK it is not possible to dry fit glue joints and then squirt glue into the joint.

What often happens is the plumbing under the kitchen sink gets bashed in the course of using the undersink space for storage or for a trash can leading to a leak. Hence some people try to make solid connections, but this cannot be done without special expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Abs is never used for pressure. Unless you're doing this for a science experiment, i.e. not for indoor plumbing, don't do this. It's not code and you may be just putting a ghetto band aid on a larger issue.

Comment: He's talking about a trap, that's not a pipe under pressure.

Comment: What I meant by "pressure" was the compression the threaded nut applies to the seal. I did not mean that the inisde of the drains was pressurized.